# How to do a cross cluster replication between Cassandra clusters?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to setup two Cassandra clusters in two different DCs. Is it possible to create a cross cluster replication between Cassandra clusters? I am trying to find that in the documentation but so far not able to get anything on this.

Answer (score 1):

Between clusters?  No.

Now, if you were to join them together as a part of the same cluster, then replicating between data centers is fairly straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Aaron stated, that is not available out of the box with open source Apache Cassandra(R) to replicate between two different clusters. You may get that capability via other commercial offerings like [DataStax Advanced Replication](https://www.datastax.com/blog/dse-advanced-replication-dse-51) or via a custom app or etc.,